# Insert multiple images (.gif) to be used as icons, not background, into different rows using CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I have to create a table with information about TV shows broadcasts, like a schedule.

So my top row are columns featuring the hours (1PM | 1:30 | 2PM...) and the left column (row) features the channels:

A&E
ABCFAM
AMC
ANPL
BBC
[etc... There are like 20 of these.]

There's an icon [gif format] that has to go before the each of the channel's name, this icon inidcates the number.

So I did this:

HTML:

```
<th scope="row"><img src="images/53.gif" alt="" class="channel-number">WPGH</th>
```

CSS:

```
.channel-number {
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
float: left;
padding-left: 2px;
padding-right: 2px;
 }
```

However, I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this with CSS. This icon isn't a background image, it's more like "content" and I have like 20 of these little gifs. What would I have to do in CSS to get them to display to the right, while the channel name displays on the left?

This is a very but very long and complicated table I'm working on and this is the one feature I can't seem to be getting right at all. I'd greatly appreciate any input.

Comment: Why don't you make a css sprite and make use of background images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the icon is considered content, then it should be in html.  It's not because it's graphical that it *has* to be handled in css.  The layout of the image should be done there, of course.

To get the image to the right of your text, simply float it to the right instead of left

```
float:right
```

it will stay inside the table cell.  Alternatively, use absolute positioning to force it to the right side and not influence the display of the channel name.

Another thing: make use of your `alt` attribute.  You can use a graphic to show a stylized number 53, but you really need to set the alt to 53 then, for the sake of screen readers, robots, textual browsers and the like.

Figuring out an alt attribute that makes sense can be difficult, but in this case it's as easy as it gets :)

```
<th scope="row"><img src="images/53.gif" alt="53" class="channel-number">WPGH</th>
```

Comment: I'm VERY sorry for not answering sooner. I followed this logic and it worked!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the site - I'm a constant but slow learner. Thanks!